# What's the geometric intuition of the notions *reduced* and *nonreduced*?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

As well known, the notion *reduce* is defined by the notion nilpotent elements. For example, a scheme $\left(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}\right)$ is reduced if for every open set $U \subseteq X$, the ring $\mathcal{O}_{X}(U)$ has no nilpotent elements; $\left(X, \mathcal{O}_{X}\right)$ is reduced if and only if for every $P \in X,$ the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ has no nilpotent elements.

**Question:  How to understand this notion?** That is to say, can someone figure out a bit more about this, what it says, what it means, how to think of it geometrically, and so on. (Sorry for my rough expression, I am unable to express it precisely, however.) Furthermore, can any one give an example to **make a distinction between the two concepts, reduced and unreduced.**

Comment: Look in "4.2 Visualizing schemes II: nilpotents" in Ravi Vakil's notes.

Comment: For examples just $Spec(k[x]/(x))$ and $Spec(k[x]/(x^2))$

Answer (score 4):

A commutative ring $R$ canonically maps to a product $\prod_P R/P$ of integral domains, where $P$ runs over all the prime ideals of $R$. The kernel of this map is the intersection $\cap P$ of all the prime ideals, which is the nilradical $\text{Nil}(R)$ (this is a classic exercise). So $R$ is reduced iff this map is injective iff $R$ embeds into a product of integral domains. Geometrically you can think of this condition as saying that elements of $R$ are determined by their "evaluations at prime ideals." This is one way to think about why "reduced" is one of the conditions defining a (not-necessarily-irreducible) variety.

The simplest example of a non-reduced ring to keep in mind is probably $k[x]/x^2$ where $k$ is, say, a field. The Spec of this ring arises naturally as a [scheme-theoretic intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme-theoretic_intersection); for example, it's the scheme-theoretic intersection of a circle and a line tangent to it (exercise). The fact that $\dim_k k[x]/x^2 = 2$ corresponds to the intuitive idea that this intersection has "multiplicity $2$," and this notion of multiplicity is one of the ingredients needed to make [Bezout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem), that a plane curve of degree $d_1$ and a plane curve of degree $d_2$ intersect in $d_1 d_2$ points, true (there are two others, namely we need to work over an algebraically closed field and we need to consider intersections at infinity).

$\text{Spec } k[x]/x^2$ also naturally arises as the "walking tangent vector"; more formally, morphisms from this object to another $k$-scheme $X$ correspond to pairs consisting of a $k$-point $x \in X(k)$ and a [Zariski tangent vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_tangent_space) to $x$. So, for example, it can be used to define the [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) of an [algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group) over $k$ (at least in characteristic $0$).

Comment: I like this a lot, but "embeds" might not be the right word since as you note the whole point is that the kernel of the map may be nontrivial!

Comment: Whoops, fixed, thanks.